# Please identify this bone found on the beach

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology, bone

I've found it on the beach in Çanakkale, Turkey. Width 7.5 cm, height 5 cm. Inner hole dimensions are 2.5 cm x 3 cm.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an atlas vertebra from a large herbivore, a goat, a young horse, a deer. Also know as the [C1 vertebra](https://www.google.com/search?q=goat%20c1%20vertebra&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiSqKq_1K_wAhUJNBQKHcs-DjMQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=goat%20c1%20vertebra&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJzoECAAQQzoCCAA6BggAEAgQHlDRnAJY4rMCYI21AmgAcAB4AIAB6gOIAaQRkgEKMTEuMC4yLjEuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=sQyRYNKLC4noUMv9uJgD&bih=710&biw=1265) it's probably a sheep from a mechoui party.

Comment: Thank you. Goat is most probable animal here on these beaches.

Comment: Hehe look at the moderators joke comment.... " A sheep is an animal which says 'mehehehe' and it's white and wooly"